# On which Stack Exchange site can I ask Windows-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question like "How to merge two drives in Windows 10 without losing my apps and data?"

Which Stack Exchange site is preferred to ask these kind of questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for [Super User](//superuser.com).

According to its [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) you can ask questions related to:

> computer software ...

Which is exactly your question area.